# Return dataframe to original state from pivot state

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am currently trying to return a dataframe to its' original state after performing some operations on the pivoted dataframe.

I basically have a dataframe which looks like: [image]

After transforming the dataframe using pivot and performing some operations on it, the dataframe looks like this where every row represented by a `date`, every column is unique combination of `appkey+cc` and the value is the `target`.

[image]

besides that, I have also added an aggregation of the sum of target under `total` which sums up daily `target` and `appkey_total` which sums up daily `target` but only for the `appkey`.

The idea is to return the pivoted table to it's original state + the `total` and `appkey_total` as added columns.

My problem is that I don't keep `appkey` and `cc` as columns in the pivot table and I concatenate the `appkey` and `cc`, so I'm not sure how to return it back?
I can't melt it because I don't have the original columns names.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**
After trying what @jezrael suggested, I got the following output:
As can be seen, the `appkey` was added as index, while the 3 unique `appkey` are stayed as column names.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `total` to index for `MultiIndex`, then split columns and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('total', append=True)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['cc','appkey'], axis=1).stack([0, 1]).reset_index()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this indeed helped me getting almost what I want. check the edit question to see what else I'm missing please

Comment: @Flika205 - Can you try `df1 = df1.rename_axis(['cc','appkey'], axis=1).stack([0, 1]).reset_index()` ?

Comment: perfect. thanks a lot!